# Verifying a Hangfire Enqueue

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, hangfire

Can anyone explain to me why when I try to verify, in a unit test, that my background job client (Hangfire) was enqueued, I get "Invalid virtual (overridable in VB).." exception, yet when this same enqueue is contained within a catch block... all is good?

Throws Exception Code Example:

```
public void GetPDF(PDFparam param){
   _backgroundClient.Enqueue(IHelper)(x => x.GetPDFHangfire(param))
}
```

Does not throw:

```
public void GetPDF(PDFparam param){
   try{
     ThisWillThrow();
   }
   catch(Exception e){
     _backgroundClient.Enqueue(IHelper)(x => x.GetPDFHangfire(param))
     throw();
   }
}
```

and the test

```
private Mock<IBackgroundJobClient> _mockBRJClient = new Mock<IBackgroundJobClient>();   

_mockBRJClient.Verify(x => x.Enqueue<IHelper>(y => y.GetPDFHangire(It.IsAny<PDFparam>())), Times.Once);
```

I did fix the test to not throw using the approach of:

```
_backgroundJobClient.Verify(x => x.Create(
           It.Is(job => job.Method.Name == "GetPDFHangfire"),
           It.IsAny()));
```

But this is a matter of curiosity now.. any insights?

Comment: You should post the whole stacktrace (or the most relevant parts). Also which version of hangfire are you using ? in which version of .Net ?